# Node based properties on a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm starting out with Neo4J to create a graph of users and their relationships. At the moment there is a single 'KNOWS' relationship between users i.e.

[image]

What I want to do now is specify properties on the relationship specifically for each of the users. For example, "interest" which indicates how much a user is interested in the other user. Can I specify this for each user on a single KNOWS relationship or would I need to create two relationships between the users and set the attribute on each of the relationships?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your comments are of no value to others after the person you responded to reads them, then a good idea is to delete the comments. Notice that I deleted my comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I specify this (property: interest) for each user on a single KNOWS relationship or would I need to create two relationships between the users and set the attribute on each of the relationships?

You will need two relationships.

You could do it with one but then you have to keep two properties in the relationship and information about which property goes with which node. Much easier with two relationships.

From comment:

> Can I keep them as bi-directional or would I need to use directional
>   in this case?

Relationships are always directional. It is only when you query that the concept of bi-directional appears, but that is not really bi-directional, it is without direction, e.g. `(a)-[r]-(b)`. So you would use `(a)-[r]->(b)` and `(b)-[r]->(a)` or `(a)<-[r]-(b)`. If you query with the direction, then you know how to apply the relationship property.

I typically do more of my work with Java as an [embedded](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/) application instead of Cypher and it pays to use directional queries as it makes for less code to do the associations.

---

Note

Since your case is so simple, just try various methods and see what works. Remember to keep track of how long the quires take and if necessary add indexes. Also use the query profiling tool to make sure you are making effective queries.